# multiple summation in loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to solve this equation in python:

[image]

I wanted to solve it but getting doubled value for each. Not sure, why is that happening.

```
   c_var_i = [10, 13]
   y_t = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

   #y_t_i = c_var_i * (1+2+3+4+5)

   #y_t_i = [11, 15, 20, 35, 10, 33]
   k_i, I = 47, range(len(y_t))
   J = range(len(c_var_i))

   y = [sum(c_var_i[j] * [sum(y_t[i]) for i in I]) for j in J]
   y
```

And getting this output:

[image]

But it should be: 210, 273

I'm ignoring delta t first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
c_var_i = [10, 13]
y_t = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

y = [c * sum(y_t[i]) for i,c in enumerate(c_var_i)]
print(y)
```

Second version using `zip`:

```
c_var_i = [10, 13]
y_t = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

y = [c * sum(y) for c, y in zip(c_var_i, y_t)]
print(y)
```

Comment: Thanks. But y_t should have multiple arrays.

Comment: like (10*(1+2+3+4+5+6), 13*(1+2+3+4+5+6))

Comment: @FedowMakhnach Hey, I already fixed your first version to also work. But you second version looks nice as well.